# Hack or bug in boost asio echo server example?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, move

I am trying to understand the [echo server example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) from boost asio. And I cannot get **how it is possible to move many times from the same object**. Sorry, if I just miss some simple thing.

This is a method which is called on start. `socket_` is a member of class. And as I can see it is moved every time new connection established. Please, look at the [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) to understand the whole picture.

```
void do_accept()
{
  acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
      [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
      {
        if (!ec)
        {
          std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_))->start();
        }

        do_accept();
      });
}
```

Comment: I don't know this framework, but if socket is a network socket handle, then it's an integral value and it has no move constructor which means std::move() does nothing at all. For me this seems to be an error (socket_ should not be moved if its reused) which is fixed by accident (compiler does not move it because move is not supported).

Comment: @AndreasH. It does have one. Anyway thank you for your answer.

Comment: However, this framework seems really dirty to me. You should not use std::move if you expect the source to no change. This is like writing a operator+ with returns a-b ;)
Also the use of start() on a shared_ptr only makes sense if start() does not run a thread on the newly created (shared) object or if session implements shared_from_this and start creates a shared copy if this. Its not at all clear what this code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to Andreas I looked at move constructor of asio socket. I should have done it before. And the answer is simple:

> Following the move, the moved-from object is in the same state as if
>      constructed using the @c basic_stream_socket(io_service&) constructor.